# Ninject in MVC 3 application with DependencyResolver resolve service by string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

I would like to use Ninject capabilities to work with DependencyResolver so I would be able to do something like this:

```
string contentType = "Page";
IContentRepository<contentType> repository = System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IContentRepository<contentType>>();
```

`contentType` is dynamic so it can be anything (of a several options) and I don't want to write `if..else..`
Obviously the above doesn't work. I have to get the Type from the string somehow. IContentRepository is generic and accepts types that derive from ContentBase class, of which Page (in the example above) does.

In MVC 2 with the old Ninject I did it through a custom repository factory (`IRepositoryFactory`) which would take the string and then pass that along to the constructor of the repository. But that approach worked with non-generic repositories and it also required special constructors in the repository, which I would like to avoid, if possible.

This is outside of the controller, so I cannot use controller constructor injection (I have that working actually). I'm really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use reflection to call generics dynamically.

This should work:

```
var targetType = typeof(IContentRepository<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(contentType));
object repository = System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetType().GetMethod("GetService").MakeGenericMethod(targetType).Invoke(System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current, null);
```

Comment: Ok, but what then when I'm left with repository of type object? How do I call its methods?

Comment: Either cast it to a known type or keep using reflection. :)

Comment: If I could cast it to a known type, I wouldn't need doing this in the first place.